# Unable to consume a dot net web service by passing two parameters from android

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing

Now i am consuming a dot net web service in android by the method SOAP.This is the exact web service which i am trying to consume.

"http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx" this web service is actually retreiving the data in the form of xml format

The input values for this web service are

**FromDate :  01/01/2012**

**ToDate :    07/07/2012**

After giving these input values into edittext boxes,when i am clicking the "invoke" button its showing the blank screen,i cannot find any thing on my logcat too..

**Logcat**

```
09-11 11:11:41.314: D/AndroidRuntime(442): Shutting down VM
09-11 11:11:41.323: D/dalvikvm(442): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
09-11 11:11:41.374: I/AndroidRuntime(442): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
09-11 11:11:41.844: D/AndroidRuntime(450): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START      <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
09-11 11:11:41.844: D/AndroidRuntime(450): CheckJNI is ON
09-11 11:11:41.974: D/AndroidRuntime(450): --- registering native functions ---
09-11 11:11:42.034: I/jdwp(450): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
09-11 11:11:42.524: I/ActivityManager(75): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.test_webservice/.Test_webservice }
09-11 11:11:42.584: D/AndroidRuntime(450): Shutting down VM
09-11 11:11:42.604: D/dalvikvm(450): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
09-11 11:11:42.714: I/AndroidRuntime(450): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
09-11 11:11:48.973: D/dalvikvm(178): GC_EXPLICIT freed 438 objects / 20576 bytes in 100ms
```

Suggestions please?

Comment: @LalitPoptani i have given my logcat for reference on the above question.please find it

Comment: this is not the required output from logcat, I am asking for error/exeception that you are getting.

Comment: @LalitPoptani no..i got only these things on my log-cat,i have mentioned this line too on my question.

Comment: make sure your button's click event is working then.

Comment: Yeah im sure its working well,but actually i have added some code and class for consuming the above web service,because the above web service is returning the data in the form of XML dataset

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16524/discussion-between-manick-and-lalit-poptani)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you're using ksoap2, but I wrote and tested this function and it works fine, I'm getting the values. Hope it helps:

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public void getTMSChart(String FromDate, String ToDate)
{
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");        
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);        
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    String namespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String url = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";
    String method = "GetTMSChart";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method);        
    request.addProperty("FromDate", FromDate);               
    request.addProperty("ToDate", ToDate);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(namespace + method, envelope);
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        SoapObject root =  (SoapObject) ((SoapObject)(result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");
        int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++)
        {
            SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
            int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();
            for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++)
            {           
                String orderNo =  table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No");
                int freightRate = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));
                int marginPercent = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent"));
                // whatever you do with these values
            }                   
        }
    }   
    catch (Exception e) {

    }   
}
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is, i need to create a bar-chart,just by consuming this web service's values ie., Order_no for x-axis,freight_Rate for y-axis and finally Margin_percent is to show at the top of the each created bar...this is what i want,can you please help me?

Comment: can you show me the .xml for the above code i am just trying your suggestion now?

Comment: I tried it with your suggested values:
FromDate : 01/01/2012
ToDate : 07/07/2012

And I get this:
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<Order_No>OR00000001</Order_No>
<Freight_Rate>450</Freight_Rate>
<Margin_Percent>70</Margin_Percent>
</Table>
<Table>
<Order_No>OR00000002</Order_No>
<Freight_Rate>450</Freight_Rate>
<Margin_Percent>89</Margin_Percent>
</Table>
<Table>
<Order_No>OR00000004</Order_No>
<Freight_Rate>225</Freight_Rate>
<Margin_Percent>87</Margin_Percent>
</Table>
<Table>
<Order_No>OR00000005</Order_No>
<Freight_Rate>300</Freight_Rate>
<Margin_Percent>50</Margin_Percent>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>

Comment: oh..okay...At the bottom of the code which you have given to me,you mentioned in comment line as //what ever you do with these values.        if i just want to print those values on the textview how to do it..

Comment: Which means after given the input values to the edittext boxes and if i click the button it should just show these values on a textView...I have tried this but showing some error, will i post my sources for reference on the above question

Comment: I need your help, because i am following your suggested code (which is  given by you above)

Answer (score 0):

The web service is infact not returning valid output for all dates submitted. By trial error, the web service returned valid output for

FromDate: 01/09/2012

ToDate: 05/09/2012

**edit:**

using above values i am able to obtain following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <GetTMSChartResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <GetTMSChartResult>
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
           <Table>
              <Order_No>OR00000004</Order_No>
              <Freight_Rate>225</Freight_Rate>
              <Margin_Percent>87</Margin_Percent>
           </Table>
        </NewDataSet>
     </GetTMSChartResult>
  </GetTMSChartResponse>
```